# qt don't want to scroll

Tags: c++, qt

I have a main widget in which there are some buttons, label, listbox, etc, and also 2 scroll areas. In the scroll area I show the graph. But in the scroll area my whole graph is not visible at the same time. I want to show my whole graph in the same space which means that the graph must adjust to fit in that particular area. What should i do? Someone suggested QVBoxLayout but I don't find it in the tool list.

So far I have done this

```
myplot * p = new myplot(gao.structpayloadgraph,gao1.structpayloadgraph, gao.structcol-2, "payload");

myplot * p1 = new myplot(gao.structsessiongraph,gao.structsessiongraph ,gao.structcol-2, "session");
p->resize(ui->scrollArea->size().width() ,ui->scrollArea->size().height());
p->show();
p1->resize(ui->scrollArea_2->size().width() ,ui->scrollArea_2->size().height());
p1->show();
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(p);
ui->scrollArea_2->setWidget(p1);
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setring the [widgetResizable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) property of scroll area to **true** ?.

By default it is false and scroll area honors the size you have given.

Comment: sir i have written  ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true) but its still the same am i do it wrong. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p->setSizePolicy (QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

and after call to

```
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(p);
```

call `p->adjustSize()` to fit the scroll area size.